# Is it okay to use data-attributes to store Javascript 'state'

Tags: javascript

I often use data-attributes to store configuration that I can't semantically markup so that the JS will behave in a certain way for those elements. Now this is fine for pages where the server renders them (dutifully filling out the data-attributes).

However, I've seen examples where the javascript writes data-attributes to save bits of data it may need later. For example, posting some data to the server. If it fails to send then storing the data in a data-attribute and providing a retry button. When the retry button is clicked it finds the appropriate data-attribute and tries again.

To me this feels dirty and expensive as I have to delve into the DOM to then dig this bit of data out, but it's also very easy for me to do.

I can see 2 alternative approaches:

One would be to either take advantage of the scoping of an anonymous Javascript function to keep a handle on the original bit of data, although this may not be possible and could perhaps lead to too much "magic".

Two, keep an object lying around that keeps a track of these things. Instead of asking the DOM for the contents of a certain data-attribute I just query my object.

I guess my assumptions are that the DOM should not be used to store arbitrary bits of state, and instead we should use simpler objects that have a single purpose. On top of that I assume that accessing the DOM is more expensive than a simpler, but specific object to keep track of things.

What do other people think with regards to, performance, clarity and ease of execution?

Comment: It depends on how the "data" values are set. If it's via a library like jQuery, then they're not stored in the DOM anyway; it's a big map maintained by the library. In other words, it's just a JavaScript data structure.

Comment: why not using localStorage and/or webStorage? it can be cleaner.

Comment: @Pointy But surely that JavaScript data structure is not stored in a simple/fast associative array as it relies on selectors.

Comment: @IdoGreen I don't need to store the state between page reloads so there is no need to store it using localStorage/webStorage. I would also have to serialize the data, then unserialize it (the same as I would if I was storing it in the DOM). I guess though it would be a simpler way of accessing the data than storing it in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumptions are very good!  Although it's allowed and perfectly valid, it's not a good practice to store data in the DOM.  Sure, it's fine if you only have one input field, but, but as the application grows, you end up with a jumbled mess of data everywhere...and as you mentioned, the DOM is SLOW.

The bigger the app, the more essential it is to separate your interests:

DOM Events -> trigger JS functions -> access Data (JS object, JS API, or AJAX API) -> process results (API call or DOM Change)

I'm a big fan of creating an API to access JS data, so you can also trigger new events upon add, delete, get, change.